# select dynamic div created by loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a dives by loop PHP, how i can select div from them, to change it with css, div i want select (circle), i want select div number 4 from 6 dives

```
         <?php 
            $loop = new WP_Query ( array(
                'post_type'  => 'how_it_work',
                'orderby'    => 'post_id',
                'order'      => 'ASC'
            ) );
        ?>

         <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop ->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="circle">
            <?php 
                if( has_post_thumbnail () ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                }
            ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: target it with css? `.circle {whateverCSS:here;}`

Comment: i want select div number 4 from 6 dives

Comment: you could add a counter, or you could target the fourth circle.

Comment: like `.circle:nth-of-type(4) {whateverCSS:here;}`

Comment: or something like that

Comment: target by what ?
i tried nth()
but nothing changed

Comment: it's work , thank you ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code can help :

```
     <?php $i=0; ?>
     <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop ->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <?php 
                  $i++;
                  $class='';
                  if($i>=4 && $i<=6)
                  {
                      $class=' newcss ';
                  }


            ?>
            <div class="circle <?php echo esc_attr($class); ?>">
            <?php 
                if( has_post_thumbnail () ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                }
            ?>
            </div>
```

Now you can have specific class for 4th div to 6th div and you can modify the clause as per your choices. And Just write the css with the specific class which will effect in those divs.

Hope this will work.